# PHP - Script to manipulate/replace function parameters in a PHP file?

Tags: php, parameters, file-get-contents, parentheses

I'm writing a script (in PHP) which will go through a PHP file, find all instances of a function, replace the function name with another name, and manipulate the parameters. I'm using `get_file_contents()` then `strpos()` to find the positions of the function, but I'm trying to find a good way to extract the parameters once I know the position of the start of the function. Right now I'm just using loop which walks through the next characters in the file string and counts the number of opening and closing parentheses. Once it closes the function parameters it quits and passes back the string of parameters. Unfortunately, runs into trouble with quotes enclosing parentheses (i.e. `function_name(')', 3)`). I could just count quotes too, but then I have to deal with escaped quotes, different types of quotes, etc.

Is there a good way to, knowing the start of the function, to grab the string of parameters reliably? Thank you much!

Comment: You're probably looking for a _tokenizer_

Comment: https://github.com/nikic/tokenstream

Comment: @kingkero: Thanks for the quick reply. How could I use tokenizer to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**
In case i didn't read the question carefully, if you want to only get function parameters,you can see these example :

```
$content_file = 'function func_name($param_1=\'\',$param_2=\'\'){';
preg_match('/function func_name\((.*)\{/',$content_file,$match_case);
print_r($match_case);
```

but if you want to manipulate the function, read below.

---

How about these :

1. read file using `file_get_contents();`
2. use `preg_match_all();` to get all function inside that file.
3. please not that i write `/*[new_function]*/` inside that file to identify EOF.

I use this to dynamically add/ delete function without have to open that php files.

Practically, it should be like this :

```
//I use codeigniter read_file(); function to read the file.
//$content_file = read_file('path_to/some_php_file.php');
//i dont know whether these line below will work.
$content_file = file_get_content('path_to/some_php_file.php');
//get all function inside php file.
preg_match_all('/function (.*)\(/',$content_file,$match_case);
//
//function name u want to get
$search_f_name = 'some_function_name';
//
for($i=0;$i<count($match_case[1]);$i++){ 
    if(trim($match_case[1][$i]) == $search_f_name){ 
        break;
    } 
}
//get end position by using next function start position
if($i!=count($match_case[1])-1){
    $next_function= $match_case[1][$i+1];
    $get_end_pos = strripos($content_file,'function '.$next_function);
} else {
    //Please not that i write /*[new_function]*/ at the end of my php file 
    //before php closing tag ( ?> ) to identify EOF. 
    $get_end_pos = strripos($content_file,'/*[new_function]*/');
}
//get start position
$get_pos = strripos($content_file,'function '.$search_f_name);
//get function string
$func_string = substr($content_file,$get_pos,$get_end_pos-$get_pos);
```

you can do `echo $func_string;` to know whether these code is running well or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use a real parser, like this one:

https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser

Using this library, you can manipulate the source code as a tree of "node" objects, rather than as a string, and write it back out.